# Firebase Functions, admin.database().ref(...).get() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an Android Application and am using firebase as the back end for it. I am trying to get a notification system working that relies on listening to changes in the database. Having problems though as I am getting the following error. Wondered if anyone would be able to help, any extra code can be supplied.

**Firebase Function**

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}").onWrite((data, context)=>{

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    console.log("User ID : " + user_id + " | Notification ID : " + notification_id);

    return admin.database().ref("Notifications/" + user_id + "/" + notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {

      const job_id = queryResult.data().Job;

      const from_data = admin.database().ref("Jobs/" + job_id).get();
      const to_data = admin.database().ref("Users/" + user_id).get();

      return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {

        const job_name = result[0].data().advertName;
        const to_name = result[1].data().fullName;

        console.log("JOB : " + job_name + " | TO : " + to_name);

        return undefined;
      });


    });
});
```

**Function Error**

[image: Function Error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up the Realtime Database and Firestore APIs. Firebase Realtime Database APIs doens't provide a get() method to fetch data.  For that, you use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) on a Reference object.

Comment: Really, but in the docs it says something different - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get

Comment: @Oush A new get() method was added for RTDB since this answer was posted four years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty explicit: there is no `get` function in the a Firebase Realtime Database.

You seem to be trying to use Cloud Firestore, which is available under `admin.firestore()`. So something like:

```
 const from_data = admin.firestore().doc("Jobs/" + job_id).get();
 const to_data = admin.firestore().doc("Users/" + user_id).get();
```

For full samples see the <kbd>NODE.JS</kbd> tab in the [Getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and other Firestore documentation.