# Firebase admin.database().ref().set() fails in Firebase Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How do I write to Realtime Database from a Firebase Function?
And why does the function always silently fail when it gets to the realtime db?

It seems like I can get a reference to the database, but I can't save any values.

```
try {
  functions.logger.log(`ref: ${JSON.stringify(admin.database().ref(collectionName))}`);
  await admin.database().ref(collectionName).set(value)
  .then(() => {
    functions.logger.log(`value written`);
    // Success ... do stuff
  })
  .catch(error => {
    functions.logger.log(`Catch #2: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    res.status(502).send(error);
  });
} catch (error) {
  functions.logger.log(`Catch: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
  res.status(401).send(`Having troublle writing`);
}
```

outputs:

```
ref: "https://myrealtimedb.firebaseio.com/collectionName" 
Catch: {}
Function execution .... finished with status code: 401
```

My functions can successfully create and read values from the Cloud Firestore, but is having trouble handling Realtime DB interactions.

Setting up the function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as express from 'express';

admin.initializeApp();
const main = express();
const appRoutes = new routes();

main.use('/api/', appRoutes.setupRoutes());
main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(main);
```

(I have many other functions setup in `appRoutes` and they all work fine with firestore. )

Comment: *firebaser here* If you open the Realtime Database panel for this project in the Firebase console, does it show a database?

Comment: Yes. I can successfully read/write to that database directly from a web app.

Comment: Interesting. Can you show how you initialize the `admin` variable in your question too?

Comment: Sure. It's just using the default `admin.initializeApp();`

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what could be causing the problem. I hope someone else spots it.

Comment: Searching on StackOverflow I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901729/firebase-functions-admin-database-ref-get-is-not-a-function) post which is related to the get() operation and not set(), however, have you tried using the [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) on a Reference object instead?

Comment: `once()` is a read operation. I was trying to do a write operation.